# Заменить звук уведомления на сайте vk.com с помощью js

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, google-chrome, консоль

Я знаю о существовании расширения для браузера на эту тему, но меня интересует решение этого вопроса со стороны пользователя (консоль, букмарклет)

Из того, что у меня получилось найти по этой теме, так это только расположение оригинальных звуков уведомления`*1` и ответственный за это скрипт`*2`

```
*1
https://vk.com/mp3/bb1.mp3
https://vk.com/mp3/bb2.mp3
https://vk.com/mp3/bb3.mp3

*2
https://vk.com/js/cmodules/web/notifier.js?72053950056
```

Что делать дальше с этой информацией я не знаю, потому что практически ничего не смыслю в написании кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы заменить звук уведомлений, можно заменить объект `Sound` в свойстве `sound_im` глобального объекта `curNotifier`

```js
curNotifier.sound_im = new Sound("mp3/bb1")
```

Где в качестве аргумента, конструктору "класса" `Sound` передаётся часть uri требуемого звукового файла.

Возможно, в зависимости от настроек, потребуется изменить другое свойство объекта `curNotifier`, а именно `sound` или `sound_im_current`

```js
curNotifier.sound = new Sound("mp3/bb1")
curNotifier.sound_im_current = new Sound("mp3/bb1")
```

Так же, перед заменой, возможно, потребуется убедиться в том, что глобальный объект `curNotifier` существует и был инициализирован. Иначе нужно будет дождаться этой инициализации, либо инициировать инициализацию самому